# Eclipse "unhandled event loop exception"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

my eclipse doesn't work anymore. Since a few days eclipse load and load something, till i'm quitting it. If i'm do nothing, eclipse shows "unhanded event loop exception" after a while, but continue loading and i just can quit it. I'm using the Android-SDK plugin. 
Im using a macbook with Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63). CPU and RAM should be enough. All other programs are running perfectly, so it's must be a problem with eclipse.

Can anyone help?

Thanks for help
Mats

Comment: Look at eclipse log file for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downloading a new eclipse and import your projects to a new workspace.
Maybe switching to the old workspace would not be a good idea, it'll possibly make the new eclipse crash.